# Java AddObserver(this) when in static main

Tags: java, static, observable, observers

So I have a function declared like`public class Main implements Observer{}` inside i have the main function `public static void main(String[] args) {}` and inside it, I'd like to do this `ObservableClass.addObserver(this)`. But since the main is `static` I'm not able to do that, and adding a method to the Main class won't fix the problem either since it will be called from a `static` function anyways.
Basically I want the `Main class` to be an observer and implement a method `update()`.
Does someone know a way to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: you need to instantiate your class from within main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go something like this:

```
public class Main implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        observable.addObserver(new Main());
    }
}
```

The `main` method would be better to move to another class,
whose only job is to start the main application.
Having a `main` method that starts the application inside an `Observer` implementation looks suspiciously like a violation of the [*single responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In other words, `Main` should not implement `Observer`. It should be another class that implements `Observer`. The `Main` class should have just a `main` method, configure and launch the application, and do nothing else.

Comment: but wouldn't it make the new Main() class the observer? Not the one I'm executing? I finally created another class which implements Observer, and the Main function just calls the principal function of the new class

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. `Main` should not implement `Observer`. It should be another class that implements `Observer`. The `Main` class should have just a `main` method, configure and launch the application, and do nothing else.